# Linq to SQL on Mono?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, mono

Is it possible "in anyway" that I can use Linq to SQl on a Mono project?
If it's actually .net port then if I import the System.data.Linq and the DBML that generated in VS, will it work?

THanks!

Answer (score 4):

Mono 2.6 comes with [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/). It's not user friendly though and you have to go through some pain before you can make it work.

Comment: it only support mysql, postgres and oracle, is there any other alternative that can support mssql?

Comment: @DucDigital, I believe they do support MS SQL, they do have tests for that use case: http://groups.google.com/group/dblinq/web/unit-tests?pli=1 But I'm not sure how mature that feature is, most likely not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Since Mono 2.6 you can use DbLinq however it's currently only in preview and beta is planned in Mono 2.8 release. Some queries works there (for example everything from NerdDinner MVC tutorial) but complex stuff won't work. You can read more about current status of DbLinq [here](http://groups.google.com/group/dblinq/browse_frm/thread/8260047816a6a148?pli=1).